# Java xml parser loop

Tags: java, xml, dom, saxparser

I have this xml file:

```
<root>
    <application>
        <interface />
        <interface />
    </application>

    <datatransmit>
        <interface />
    </datatransmit>
</root>
```

What I am trying to do is first do a loop through the interfaces within the `<application>` tags and then another loop through the interfaces withing the `<datatransmit>` tags.

I tried this with this Java code:

```
NodeList application = doc.getElementsByTagName("application");
for (int i = 0; i < application.getLength(); i++) {
    NodeList interfaces = doc.getElementsByTagName("interface");
    for (int j = 0; j < interfaces.getLength(); j++) {
        do some stuff...
    }
}
```

I noticed that with this loop, it goes through a loop of all the interface elements. Not just the interfaces withing the `application` tags but also the interfaces within `datatransmit`.
What would be a way to solve this?

Comment: Replace `NodeList interfaces = doc.getElementsByTagName("interface");` with `NodeList interfaces = ((Element) application.get(i)).getElementsByTagName("interface");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearly there.

Your problem is using `doc` as your root again in:

```
NodeList interfaces = doc.getElementsByTagName("interface");
```

Meaning it will search the whole document. Instead, you should use the `getElementsByTagName` method on the application Element, to limit the range of your search:

```
NodeList application = doc.getElementsByTagName("application");
for (int i = 0; i < application.getLength(); i++) {
  Element applicationElement = (Element) application.item(i);
  NodeList interfaces = applicationElement.getElementsByTagName("interface");
  for (int j = 0; j < interfaces.getLength(); j++) {
    do some stuff...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See the javadoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getElementsByTagName%28java.lang.String%29)

`getElementsByTagName()` returns all *descendants*, and since you call `doc.getElementsByTagName()` you get all descendants of `doc` which match the element name, rather than all descendants of your `application` element

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the list of `application` nodes from here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < application.getLength(); i++) {
   Node appNode = application.item(i);
   ....
}
```

and inspect the name/tag of the node via `getNodeName()` for the value `interface`.

That applies for getting `interface` as a child of `application`. If `interface` *only* occurs under `application`, then you can skip the first step and simply do

```
NodeList interfaces = doc.getElementsByTagName("interface");
```

Perhaps a more concise/flexible solution would be to use [XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java), with a path such as `/root/application/interface` ?

Answer (score 1):

As you are lopping through all elements from `document` you are getting all elements.

`doc.getElementsByTagName("interface");`

You should get elements from each `application` tag object.